# ViewpagerIndicator use with SherlockFragmentActivity or ListFragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, viewpagerindicator

In my project im using [actionBarSherlok](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)  library and is working fine. 
I want to implement the google play app, beautiful widgets effect. For that i found the following [library](http://viewpagerindicator.com/).

And also works. But my problem is how can i combine the secod librery to be use with listfragment or with SherlockFragmentActivity (which i prefer).

Example code:
- TestFragment is just a Fragment class. getItem is the method that returns the fragment that will be show when the user move the finger on the screen right? If its an @override method how can i show on screen other class than Fragment?
Do i need to create an adapter, if this is the case how i know what i have to keep in mind? or is there one for this type of things?

I think im missing something.

```
class GoogleMusicAdapter extends TestFragmentAdapter implements TitleProvider {
    public GoogleMusicAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return TestFragment.newInstance(SampleTabsDefault.CONTENT[position % SampleTabsDefault.CONTENT.length]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return SampleTabsDefault.CONTENT.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle(int position) {
        return SampleTabsDefault.CONTENT[position % SampleTabsDefault.CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Regards.

Comment: @Jake Wharton Would like to have a look here?

Comment: This is a ViewPager question, not ViewPagerIndicator-related.

Comment: @Jake, hi. Beside is ViewPager. Is it possible and do u have any tutorial about this? Regards